# How to change the location of the splash screen image?

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, user-interface

I moved all of my images into their respective 'image' folder in my solution. Now I want to correctly update the application such that I can see my splash screen image. I've managed to do this with the other images, but not the splash screen image. I can't seem to find any way to programmatically specify where the image is located. As of now, I just see a black screen for my splash screen. Here's an image of what my solution's file structure looks like:

[image: My new file structure]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. The OS looks for a `SplashScreenImage.jpg` in the root of the XAP.

You can create your own custom splash page instead if you really want to.

Comment: +1 for custom splash page. http://newtonapps.com/post/2010/06/30/Windows-Phone-7-Customized-Splash-Screen-TrickTip.aspx

Comment: Hmm that's cool, but I moved the image back into the root of the XAP, and i still see black as the splash screen, when the image clearly isn't black. I've tried rebuilding. Any other ideas?

Comment: Never mind, i just changed it to a .jpg, and everything worked well. I am curious as to why it didn't work as a png though.

Comment: Ah, sorry. It's the ApplicationIcon and Background that can be PNGs. The splashscreen is always JPEG.