# Changing the path/filename of SplashScreenImage.jpg in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, splash-screen

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8 Project, and I'd like to move all the image files into the Assets folder. I can move all the tiles and icons to another folder and update their paths in the project's properties, but I can't seem to change the path of the SplashScreenImage.jpg file.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967638/how-to-change-the-location-of-the-splash-screen-image)
seems to solve my problem for Windows Phone 7, but has this been updated in WP8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, still the same "problem", splash screens must be placed at root level. However, you can have several splash screens depending on the client's resolution. Check here for more tips on how to create splash screens for your WP apps.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769511%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: That's a bit disappointing, but thanks very much for your help :)